# calculate mean of a column in a data frame when it initially is a character

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame in which all columns are seen as character but some of them have only numerical values. How can I calculate the mean of these columns?
I tried

```
good$V1 <- as.numeric(good$V1)
good$V2 <- as.numeric(good$V2)
good$V3 <- as.numeric(good$V3)
```

but when I demanded the mean later it still gave me NA as answer.

```
mean(good$V1)
```

Also: Is it possible that I get the mean of good$V1, good$V2,... all in one instruction?
This doesnt work:

```
colMeans(good[sapply(good, is.numeric, na.rm=TRUE)])
```

Where can I put the na.rm=TRUE so it works?

Comment: we need a [mcve] please ... `str(good$V1)`? have you tried `mean(good$V1, na.rm=TRUE)` ?

Comment: Hey thanks, this works! Do you know as well know if there's a possibility that i get the mean of multiple columns in one instruction?

Comment: Try `colMeans` with `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Coincidentally, that's what I just tried but I don't know where to fit in the `na.rm = TRUE` w/o getting an error. Because this isn't accepted: `colMeans(good[sapply(good, is.numeric, na.rm=TRUE)])`

Comment: The structure of your data set still isn't entirely clear to me.  Can you edit your question with the results of `str(good)` ?

Comment: All questions are now answered anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```r
mean(good$V1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

or

```r
colMeans(good[sapply(good, is.numeric)], 
         na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: You're my hero haha, it works. I tried the na.rm=T part in between the )] but not between ])